# Load Data From Database PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need to transfer data from my HTML table to my modal(I am not using bootstrap). As you can see from the image below, I displayed the data from my MySQL database into the table.

The problem is when I click the EDIT button of the 1st row the data will be transferred to my modal. However, when I click the EDIT button of the 2nd row the data transferred to my modal is still the data of the 1st row. Please help me in fixing this problem. I am still learning PHP and JavaScript.

[Table Data Generation Here |](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mAYV.png)
[Modal Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqiVc.png)

PHP Code:

```php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr class='table-row'>
    <td class='table-cell'>".$row['program']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'>".$row['project_name']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'>".$row['department']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'>".$row['start_date']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'>".$row['end_date']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'><span style='color:".$color."'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i></span> ".$row['priority']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'><span style='color:".$color_2."'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i></span> ".$row['status']."</td>
    <td class='table-cell'><a id='edit-modal-show' class='btn btn-edit'>Edit</a>
        <div class='editProject-modal' id='edit-project-modal'>
            <div class='editProject-modal-dialog'>
                <div class='editProject-modal-content'>
                    <div class='editProject-onboard'>
                        <header class='onboard-header'>
                            <h1 class='onboard-title'>Edit Project</h1>
                            <button class='onboard-close-2'>
                                <i class='fa fa-close'></i>
                            </button>
                        </header>
                    <div class='onboard-body'>
                    <form autocomplete='off' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' id='".$row['project_id']."' name='p-id' value=".$row['project_id'].">
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Program</label>
                                        <input type='text' placeholder='Program' name='program' id='pr-".$row['project_id']."' class='form-control' value='".$row['program']."' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Project Name</label>
                                        <input type='text' placeholder='Project Name' name='pname' id='pn-".$row['project_id']."' class='form-control' value='".$row['project_name']."' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Project Description</label>
                                        <textarea type='text' placeholder='Project Description' name='description' id='desc-".$row['project_id']."' class='form-control' required>".$row['description']."</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Lead Department</label>
                                        <select class='form-control' name='department' required>
                                            <option value=''>Department</option>";
                                            if ($count_2> 0) {
                                                while ($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2)) {
                                                    if ($row_2['department'] == $row['department']){
                                                        $selected = "selected";
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        $selected = "";
                                                    }
                                                    echo "<option value='".$row_2['department']."'".$selected.">".$row_2['department']."</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        echo"</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Start Date</label>
                                        <input type='date' name='s-date' id='s-date-".$row['project_id']."' class='form-control' value='".$row['start_date']."' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>End Date</label>
                                        <input type='date' name='e-date' id='e-date-".$row['project_id']."' class='form-control' value='".$row['end_date']."' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='form-field'>
                                        <label class='field-label'>Priority</label>
                                        <select class='form-control' name='priority' id='priority' required>
                                        <option value=''>Priority</option>";
                                        if ($count_3 > 0) {
                                            while ($row_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_3)) {
                                                if ($row_3['priority'] == $row['priority']){
                                                    $selected = "selected";
                                                }
                                            else {
                                                $selected = "";
                                            }
                                            echo "<option value='".$row_3['priority']."'".$selected.">".$row_3['priority']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    echo "</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='column-2'>
                                    <div class='onboard-btn'>
                                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-update' name='update'>Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class='table-cell'><a href='delete.php?del=".$row['project_id']."' class='btn btn-delete'>Delete</i></a></td>
    </tr>";
    }
```

Javascript:

```
/* Edit Project Modal Event */
var modal_edit = document.getElementById('edit-project-modal');
var span_edit = document.getElementsByClassName("onboard-close-2")[0];

$(document).on('click',".btn-edit",function(){
    $(modal_edit).toggleClass("edit-modal-show");
});

span_edit.onclick = function() {
    $(modal_edit).removeClass("edit-modal-show");   
}
```

Comment: `id` must be unique on the page.

Comment: @u_mulder can you fix my javascript code? i think its the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it does not know which edit button is related to witch modal.
use

```js
var modal_edit;

$(document).on('click',".btn-edit",function(){
   modal_edit = $(this).parent().find(".edit-project-modal");
   $(modal_edit).toggleClass("edit-modal-show");
});
$(".onboard-close-2").click(function(){
  $(modal_edit).removeClass("edit-modal-show");
});
```

An other thing I know this is not related to your request but it will give you wrong result when you fix this problem. The form in the model should have a unique name such as your record id so that when it submits it you know which form has been submitted.

P.S. - If you are using double quotes in echo() then rather than doing `.." . $PHPVariable . "..` use can directly write `echo "<p id='$PHPVariable'>"` double quotes can parse PHP Variables, but beware of messing up the single and double quotes.

Comment: It's working but the department dropdown and priority is not generating the data

Comment: For those you are fetching the data in the wrong place.

Comment: Oh I got it now! Thank you! one little problem the close button in my modal wont close my modal can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do this  in your listing page you have to call onClick method on the button taking the respecting id as an argument

```
<td  onClick="editRow(<?php echo $value['id']; ?>);"><?php echo ($value['display_offer']); ?></td>
```

and then by using ajax in the function get the respective value according to the id and populate the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the same Id for every edit modal. ID must be unique on a page.

You can fix it in two ways:

1. Use a counter variable inside loop **$counter** and assign ids like `...id='edit-project-modal-".$counter."'>` in this way you will get unique ids like *edit-project-modal-1*, *edit-project-modal-1*.
2. Make a single Modal and dynamically add content to it when edit button is clicked. In this way, you have a single modal with unique Id and also page size will be smaller. For adding content you can make good use of **data** attributes or jQuery's .closest() and .find() methods.

Some Suggestions:

1. Use `<p id='$phpvariables'>` directly if you are using echo() with double quotes. double quotes can parse PHP variables.
2. Use bootstrap's Modal only build see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ to avoid modal related bugs.

Comment: i am try your method number 1 I have added a unique id for each modal how about my javascript how can I display my modal when I click the edit button?

Comment: you have to bind click event to your button element that triggers the modal. this is explained by @Sanjit Bhardwaj in above answer.

Comment: Cool, if you are learning basic PHP then avoid concepts like Modals etc because they require a good knowledge of CSS, DOM and JS to work properly in every case. All the best for your learning